# Linear functional equations

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, functional-equations

Linear functional equations like $(x + 1)P (x) = (x − 10)P (x + 1)$ are fairly common in competition math, and there are some general techniques for proving things about the solutions, such as degree of polynomial solutions, highest or lowest degree coefficients, etc.

One could imagine a somewhat general theory for functional equations of the form $L f = g$, with $f$ the unknown, $g$ a given function, and $L$ a linear operator composed of the basic operations of multiplication by $x$, i.e. $f(x) \mapsto x f(x)$, and shifts $f(x) \mapsto f(x+a)$.  **Are there any published works on the theory of such equations?**

Comment: They are commonly referred to as "finite difference equations".

Comment: The book [A = B](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html) and the chapter on generating functions in [Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf) contain techniques that are useful. The particular example that you wrote is an hypergeometric term. The first book contains algorithms to deal with sums and difference equations of those, to determine when the solution can be written as a constant sum of hypergeometric terms. Things like that.

Answer (score 2):

You're talking about *[Difference Equations](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/difference-equation)*. But you could also interpret it as a *[Recurrence Equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RecurrenceEquation.html)* or as a *[Finite Difference Equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FiniteDifference.html)*. You could also interperate it as a $0$th-order *[Difference](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Difference-DifferentialEquation.html)* / *[Delay Differential Equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DelayDifferentialEquation.html)*, or a delay equation (but that's probably less said).

---

---

In *[Applications of the Symbolic Toolbox](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/B9780128122563000191)* (Chapter $10.13$) by *George Lindfield* and *John Penny* they show a good method to solve such equations with constant coefficients. They use the unilateral [$\mathcal{Z}$ transform](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Z-Transform.html) with its usefull property of linearity and (where $\mathcal{Z}_{x}\left[ y\left( x \right) \right]\left( z \right) = Y\left( z \right)$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}$):
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{Z}_{x}\left[ y\left( x + k \right) \right]\left( z \right) = z^{k} \cdot Y\left( z \right) - \sum\limits_{m = 0}^{k - 1}\left[ z^{k - m} \cdot y\left( m \right) \right]\\
\mathcal{Z}_{x}\left[ y\left( x + k \right) \right]\left( z \right) = z^{-k} \cdot Y\left( z \right) + \sum\limits_{m = 1}^{k}\left[ z^{m - k} \cdot y\left( -m \right) \right]\\
\end{align*}
$$

An example that they give is "$6 \cdot y\left( x \right) - 5 \cdot y\left( x - 1 \right) + y\left( x - 2 \right) = 4^{-x}$" and their solution is "$y\left( x \right) = \frac{5}{2} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{x} - 2 \cdot \left( \frac{1}{3} \right)^{x} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)^{x}$" wich is correct - [see here for prove](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=6%20y%5Bx%5D%20-%205%20y%5Bx%20-%201%5D%20%2B%20y%5Bx%20-%202%5D%20where%20y%5Bx%5D%20%3D%205%2F2%20%281%2F2%29%5Ex%20-%202%20%281%2F3%29%5Ex%20%2B%201%2F2%20%281%2F4%29%5Ex).

This method is also mentioned in *[TRANSFORM METHODS](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/B0122270851001582)* (*Chapter $Z$-transforms*) by *S. Braun*.

Another method to search for the homogeneous solution is reduction to the characteristic equation as discussed in *[Theory and Applications of Numerical Analysis](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780125535601/theory-and-applications-of-numerical-analysis)* (Chapter $13$ - *ORDINARY DIFFERENTIAL EQUATIONS*) by *G.M. PHILLIPS* and *P.J. TAYLOR*. You can find this method applied [here](https://people.math.umass.edu/%7Elr7q/ps_files/teaching/math456/Chapter3.pdf) too. More generally applied, you can find this method in *[Probability](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/2003/Probability/prob07.pdf)* (Chapter $7$ - *DIFFERENCE EQUATIONS*).

---

A work focused directly on polynomial solutions of difference equations is *[Polynomial solutions of algebraic difference equations and homogeneous symmetric polynomials](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S074771711930135X)* by *Olha Shkaravska* and *Marko van Eekelen* (this article is even free to read):

> This article addresses the problem of computing an upper bound of the degree $d$ of a polynomial solution $P\left( x \right)$ of an algebraic difference equation of the form $G\left( x \right) \left( P\left( x - \tau_{1} \right),\, \ldots,\, P\left( x - \tau_{s} \right) \right) + G_{0}\left( x \right) = 0$ when such $P\left( x \right)$ with the coefficients in a field $\mathbb{K}$ of characteristic zero exists and where $G$ is a non-linear $s$-variable polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{K}\left[ x \right]$ and $G_{0}$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{K}$.